# Force between two parallel wires?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, alternative-proof

Having two current carrying (currents $I'$ and $I$) wires of length $a$ parallel to the $z$-axis, one with end points $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,a)$ and one from $(a,0,0)$ to $(a,0,a)$, I'm looking for the force on the second one due to the first one. Here is my problem:

I know I'm suppose to get (which I get by finding the magnetic field,...) $F=\frac{\mu_0II'}{2\pi a}a$ but I also know that I can compute this with the formula
$F=\frac{-\mu_0II'}{4\pi a}\int_0^a\int_0^a (dr'.dr) \frac{(r'-r)}{|r'-r|^3}$ where $r$ and $r'$ are along the wires. When I tried, I got rid of the absolute value by separating the second integral in two parts : $\int_0^r$ and $\int_r^a$. But I don't get anywhere near the solution! Can you help me?

Comment: You should at least post your solution so users can check its validity.

Comment: I haven't gone to the end of the computation since it doesn't give anything like the answer : it gives logarythmes, that's why I didn't put it on

Comment: I suggest you move this question to physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf r=(0,0,z)$ and $\mathbf r'=(a,0,z')$.

Then

$d\mathbf r=(0,0,dz)\;$ and $\;d\mathbf r'=(a,0,dz')$

$d\mathbf r \cdot d\mathbf r'=dz\, dz'$

$\mathbf r' - \mathbf r=(a,0,z'-z)$

$|\mathbf r' - \mathbf r|=\sqrt {a^2+(z'-z)^2}$

Consider the force exerted by the first segment$$\mathbf F=-\frac {\mu_0 II'}{4\pi}\int_0^a \int_0^a \frac {\mathbf r' - \mathbf r}{\;\;|\mathbf r' - \mathbf r|^3} \,d\mathbf r \cdot d\mathbf r'$$ By simmetry, $F_y$ and $F_z$ are null.

One has $$F_x=-\frac {\mu_0 II'}{4\pi}\int_0^a \int_0^a \frac a{\left[a^2+(z'-z)^2 \right]^{\frac 32}} dz\, dz'$$Now$$\int_0^a \frac a{\left[a^2+(z'-z)^2 \right]^{\frac 32}} dz' =\frac 1a \left[\frac z{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}} + \frac {a-z}{\sqrt {a^2+(a-z)^2}}\right]$$so $$F_x=-\frac {\mu_0 II'}{2\pi}(\sqrt 2 -1)$$ See E.B.Moullin *The Principles of Electromagnetism* (1950) pp. 37-38 as a reference.

**Note**: your supposed result is valid if a wire is much longer than the other.