# Expansion of integrand before integration?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I have the following integral as part of a calculation $$\int_{-A}^{A} \int_{-A}^{A} \frac{1}{(z^2 + d^2)^3} dz dx, $$ where $A$ is a constant. I am given the condition $d \gg z$ so I am wondering if it is permissible to expand the integrand using the binomial expansion to make the integration more tractable? Is it ok? Could someone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a physical context ?

Comment: Hi, I am computing the van der waals interaction between two parallel wires separated by a distance $d$ and length L and the pairwise interaction between atoms is $U = -C/r^6$ so my integral should read (I know the form is right, and I think the limits are also good)$$-\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}\frac{C}{((x_2-x_1)^2 + d^2)^3} dx_1 dx_2$$ where the $x_i$ are coordinates for the wires.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Any thoughts?

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807957/force-between-two-parallel-wires/813374#813374). What's your comment ?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use the van der walls interaction model to solve the problem. I have been advised elsewhere that an expansion before integration introduces large errors so the advice was to integrate exactly and then expand. The problem I am having is how to integrate exactly my expression in my last post. Polar coordinates looks good but there is a cross term which introduces further difficulties and I am not sure how to write the limits in polar coordinates for a square region in $x_1 x_2$ plane?

Comment: I should also point out that the setting up of the problem and obtaining the answer via whatever means (I.e by expansion before or after integration) is only worth 1 mark! My prof seems happy for me to expand but if I do so in another configuration of wires I obtain the same answer as the above configuration which I know is not true. So expansion is introducing errors I think.

Comment: Can you give some reference where they explain the van der waals interaction between two parallel wires ? It could be a good point of start. I think your problem pertains to the so-called _computational physics_ .

Comment: I am modelling the atom-atom van der waals interaction as $U = -C/r^6$. where $r$ is the distance between the atoms. Really I am wondering if expanding before integration is allowed?